# Как расположить список в строку, а вложенный список в колонку сразу под?

Tags: html, css

Коллеги привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне переместить ul sub-menu-sub сразу под элементом li списка sub-menu?

```css
.left-menu .sub-menu {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 37px;
  left: 40px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sub-menu-sub {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.left-menu > li:hover .sub-menu{
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<ul class="left-menu">
 {% for i in categories %}
 <li class="left-menu__item">
  <a href="{% url 'shop:product_list_by_category' i.slug %}">{{ i.name }}</a>
 # Одежда, бренд скейт, обувь итд 
   <ul class="sub-menu">
 {% for l in i.subcategories.all %}
 <li><a href="#">{{ l.name }}</a></li> # верх, низ, аксесуары 
 <ul class="sub-menu-sub">
    {% for c in l.subcategory_type.all %}
    <li><a href="#">{{ c.name }}</a></li> # кепки шапки итд 
    {% endfor %}
 </ul>
 {% endfor %}
   </ul>
 </li>
 {% endfor %}
 <li class="left-menu__item"><a href="{% url 'shop:brand_list' %}">Бренды</a></li>
 <li class="left-menu__item"><a href="#">Sale</a></li>
</ul>
```

[image: как должно выглядить]

Answer (score 0):

```
.left-menu .sub-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 62px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    width: -1px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sub-menu-sub {
    top: 37px;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;


}

.left-menu > li:hover .sub-menu {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 4444;
}
```